# how to increase image resolution in imagemagick in php

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, png

i was successfull to convert a full pdf file into different png files according to pages in pdf. But now the problem is that resolution of image is not as good as it is in pdf file, its little blurry. can anyone help me resolving this problem ?
i am using following code:-

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                           {
                         echo $msg = $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                           }
                         else
                           {
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                            }



ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);
$file1=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file='images/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$pages=exec("identify -format %n $file");
$explode=explode('.',$file);
    $explode=$explode[0];
for($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++)
{
    $im = new imagick( 'C:\wamp\www\test\upload\images\\'.$file1.'['.$i.']' ); 
    //$im->setImageColorspace(0); 
    #for thumbnail
    //$im->cropThumbnailImage(90,90);
    $im->setResolution(200,200);
    $im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(0); 
    $im->setImageFormat('png'); 
    $im->adaptiveResizeImage(768,1024);

    $im->writeImage($explode.$i.'.png'); 
    //echo $explode.$i.'.png';
    $im->clear(); 
    $im->destroy();
}
unlink($file);
```

Comment: what have you tried for values passed to `$im->setResolution` and `$im->adaptiveResizeImage`?  How did that change the image?

Comment: i dont know about $im->setResolution but $im->adaptiveResizeImage is maintaining new created png file widht and height to 768 and 1024 px

Comment: I'm not specially familiar with imagick in PHP, but I'm willing to bet a function called `setResolution` will set the resolution of the image

Answer (score 0):

Imagick's [setResolution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php) determines the resolution of the image.

Just increase the values from `200,200` to some higher number and that will increase the resolution of the image.

Comment: yes i tried this, increased its value upto 1024,768 but nothing changed

Comment: honestly, you aren't giving us much to go on.  When you say "nothing changed", do you mean that you verified the resolution and bit-depth of the image did not change, or do you just mean "it doesn't look different"?  What have you tried with imageCompression and quality?  Have you tried different files?  Programming is a lot of trial and error, so you'll have to let us know what you've tried and what happened

Comment: yes i have tried different files, also tried to increase, decrease the resolution with setResolution() , imageCompression is--> setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW), and increased and decreased setImageCompressionQuality(0). In .png created by imagemagick, photos look ok but if i convert a text pdf to .png, the text in .png looks blurred. Also i have tried functions from [http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php] @cegfault